# Migrating angular-cli to @angular/cli issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have [this](https://github.com/bradtraversy/meanauthapp) project which uses the `MEAN` stack to build a simple authentication app. When I try to serve the frontend by entering the `angular-src` directory and running `ng serve` from the Terminal I get

```
$ ng serve
Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.

The package "angular-cli" has been deprecated and renamed to "@angular/cli".

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli"
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"

The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Therefore I ran both suggested commands but then got another error:

```
$ ng serve
Environment configuration does not contain "environmentSource" entry.

A new environmentSource entry replaces the previous source entry inside environments.

To migrate angular-cli.json follow the example below:

Before:

"environments": {
"source": "environments/environment.ts",
"dev": "environments/environment.ts",
"prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}


After:

"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
"dev": "environments/environment.ts",
"prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Hence I also performed the suggested edit and finally the frontend compiled:

```
$ ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
Hash: 5af827dc707fe1859af6
Time: 14752ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 232 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 33 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 10.5 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.03 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

However, the web page at `localhost:4200` does not work correctly. When clicking a button like login nothing happens unlike before on `localhost:8080`. Now `localhost:8080` is also broken after the `angular-cli` changes I made. It only displays the text "Invalid Endpoint". I also noticed that the `Public` folder is now missing which was served from before I assume.

The reason why I need to `ng serve` is because I want to make changes to the frontend. Without changes, the web site works fine with running `MongoDB` using `mongod --dbpath data`, `npm install` and `npm start` in the root directory and then visiting `localhost:8080` but I want to be able to recompile everything and run.

Any ideas on how to fix this project for development? You can download a copy yourself and try it out in case you're unsure about some details.

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't just change dependencies when migrating to the newest angular-cli version. Please check https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update for all steps required.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle:
I read it and that's what I did. Why does the app break? I'm getting an HTTP 404 error now on the `http://localhost:4200/users/authenticate` link